# Cannot change owner of Docker Volume directory to non-root user

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am using Docker 1.4.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS with Kernel 3.13.0-4.

Consider the following Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:wheezy

VOLUME /var/myvol
# RUN mkdir /var/myvol

# copy content to volume
ADD foo /var/myvol/foo
# create user, and make it new owner of directory
RUN useradd nonroot \
    && chown -R nonroot:nonroot /var/myvol/ \
    && ls -al /var/myvol
# switch to new user
USER nonroot
# remove directory owned by user
RUN ls -al /var/myvol && rm /var/myvol/foo && ls -al /var/myvol
```

and build it with

```
touch foo
docker build -t test .
```

then the resulting output is

```
Step 0 : FROM debian:wheezy
 ---> c90d655b99b2
Step 1 : VOLUME /var/myvol
 ---> Running in d3bc83df9451
 ---> b860e18186d8
Removing intermediate container d3bc83df9451
Step 2 : ADD foo /var/myvol/foo
 ---> aded36dba841
Removing intermediate container db5dd1b08958
Step 3 : RUN useradd nonroot     && chown -R nonroot:nonroot /var/myvol/     && ls -al /var/myvol
 ---> Running in 148941cb7858
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 nonroot nonroot 4096 Feb  6 09:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root    root    4096 Feb  6 09:55 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 nonroot nonroot    0 Feb  6 09:30 foo
 ---> 144e4ff90439
Removing intermediate container 148941cb7858
Step 4 : USER nonroot
 ---> Running in 924f317b6718
 ---> 345c1586c69f
Removing intermediate container 924f317b6718
Step 5 : RUN ls -al /var/myvol && rm /var/myvol/foo && ls -al /var/myvol
 ---> Running in 16c8c2349f27
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb  6 09:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096 Feb  6 09:55 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root    0 Feb  6 09:30 foo
rm: cannot remove `/var/myvol/foo': Permission denied
INFO[0000] The command [/bin/sh -c ls -al /var/myvol && rm /var/myvol/foo && ls -al /var/myvol] returned a non-zero code: 1
```

If I'd replace the VOLUME line with the commented one below, it works perfectly. What is really strange is the output of `ls -al`: While the first says the owner was *nonroot*, the second one outputs the owner as *root*, so the `chown` command seems to be somehow discarded or the permissions resetted after switching to the new user.

Am I understanding Docker volumes in a wrong way? Is only root allowed to work with them, or may this be a bug that I should report?

[Edit]

What I want to achieve is to use a volume as data-storage for a containerized service. This service isn't required to run as root (and so I would prefer to use a non-root user), but **is** required to delete directories and files that are no longer needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you declare a directory as a `VOLUME`, you effectively can't use it in a Dockerfile any more. The basic reason is that volumes are set up when the container is run, not built.

In this case, you could simply move the `VOLUME` statement to the end of the Dockerfile. Any data in the image at that directory will be copied into the volume when the container is started.